# NSParagraphStyle how to set maximum number of lines per paragraph

Tags: ios, nsstring, uitextview, nsparagraphstyle

I am trying to achieve something like this (with the grey text always at the bottom of the textview):

[image]

but when I set the line break mode to `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` it only allows 1 line of text per paragraph like this:

[image]

I would like to truncate the first paragraph to a maximum of 2 lines and have the grey text always as the last line of text.

Comment: Does it have to use NSParagraphStyle? It looks like a UILabel w/ `.numberOfLines = 2` could work. If your constraints are correct, it'll push the subtitle down